# shadows pixelated with Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm usign Vuforia 6 and Unity 3D 5.
I'm having a problem with the shadows. The shadows look good while I'm playing in the editor, but when I export the app to an Android device the shadows look pixelated.
I've changed the shadows properties to high resolution, and I've tried with different `Shadow Distance` values, but the issue persist.

Please, anyone know how to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your device old?

Comment: No. I've tested it on three different devices, the newest one is a Samsung Galaxy S7.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You could check the quality settings for Android.

Comment: Thanks @Everts, that was the problem.  I've changed the settings for Android to 'Fantastic' and now the shadows are great.  Thank you again.

Comment: No pb but make sure it is not limiting your game on older device. Running on S7 and it is fine but trying the same settings on older may lag. You could get the specs from the device and apply the settings on start.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have it in mind.